# Want to read data from firebase but get error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make my application read this data that always change. I tried the tutorial on youtube and get an error when open the application.

Example data that I want to get to the android app:

[image: example data that I want to get to android app]

for the code, I tried this

```
package com.example.dell.smarthouse;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MenuTegangan extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mtegangan1;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_tegangan);
        mtegangan1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tegangan1);
        myRef.child("Tegangan 1").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mtegangan1.setText(value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                //Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });

    }
    }
```

Any tips about fix this code?

Comment: What's the error that you get when you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `myref` is having null pointer right? it is because you forgot to initialize it. Try this one

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = database.getReference("Tegangan 1");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mtegangan1.setText(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            //Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have not posted error log so we can not solution about specific error   but one of the reason is you are accessing `myRef` without initialization so it will generate NullPointerException, So please initialize the object before access like bellow

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```